# How to connect SQL TABLE Columns with C code

Tags: mysql, c, packet-sniffers

I want to connect the outputs of the code given below in C to the SQL Table columns  Response_Code, Command, Response_Parameter I have made in a database.

I am new in coding so help is appreciated.

```
printf("\nResponse Code: ");
for(i = 54; i<=56; i++)
    {       

    printf("%c", packet[i]);
 }
printf("\nCommand: ");
for(i = 54; i<=57; i++)
    {       
    printf("%c", packet[i]);
 }
printf("\nResponse Parameter: ");
for(i = 58; i<=104; i++)
    {       
    printf("%c", packet[i]);
 }
```

I want the outputs of Response Code,Command and Response Parameter in MYSQL TABLE columns Response_Code, Command, Response_Parameter NAMELY....PLease help

Comment: Can you show the `schema` of your database table and how packet is declared `packet`? Also what do mean by `outputs of Response Code,Command and Response Parameter `?

Comment: @kiranBiradar from outputs of Response Code,Command and Response Parameter I mean The values printed from there for loops in columns of their name respectively  packet is declared like this     const u_char *packet

Comment: Ok, can you show your database `schema`?

Comment: @kiranBiradar CREATE TABLE SMTP(Response_Code TEXT(10000) NULL,Command TEXT(10000) NULL, Response_Parameter TEXT(10000) NULL, Time_to_live BIGINT NULL, Window_Size_Value BIGINT NULL);

Comment: http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlc/ this might help you.